# keep net.tcp active in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, sockets, iis, tcp

I've wrote a web application that is also listening to a net tcp port.
the client of this web application is connecting via a plain tcp connection and everything is working great but the issue is that the IIS is stopping my site after some inactive time.

The issue is that the web application is initializing the tcp connection and any new connection is coming directly to the TCP connection without being hosted by the site.

I'm not sure how this should be solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found exactly the post that nailed it!

https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/oct/02/use-iis-application-initialization-for-keeping-aspnet-apps-alive

in general it specify that the application pool should be set to always running and the site should host the service at the pre load event that should be configured and implemented.